# Generate Random with Substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a string `main_string = "germany"`

And now I want to generate random strings that contain this `main_string`

The results should be for example:

```
 germanyXv43
 Fggermany3s
 germany55FR
```

**Whats the best way to do this?**

I thought in using `SecureRandom`

For example:

```
30000.times do 
   "germany" + SecureRandom.hex(3)
end
```

But as you can guess then `germany` would be always at the beginning of the string:

```
germany8s5
germanyDF4
......
```

How can I do it more Random? Thanks!

Comment: Generate a random number representing the character after which to insert it?  Also I'm not sure what your giant loop is for.

Comment: `SecureRandom.hex(3) + "germany" + SecureRandom.hex(3)` i guess)

Comment: @Ix00st it shouldn't be always in the middle, sometimes it should be at the front then at the end or somewhere in the middle! Thankns for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an Array and shuffle it:

```
(["germany"] + SecureRandom.hex(3).chars).shuffle.join
# => "cgermany06f96"
# => "70efgermanyb4"
# => "germany934732"
# => "ebgermany9e4f"
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was searching for!

Comment: BTW in your example you are using `SecureRandom.hex(3)` to generate random string of length 3. That is incorrect. The length of the result string is twice of n.

Comment: Thanks for that info! How many posibilites has a `String` generated with `SecureRandom.hex(3)`. Im thinking of `16 * 16 * 16` is that correct?

Comment: I guess you can calculate combinations with allowed repetition using formula: `(n+r-1)! / r!(n-1)!` that makes total `54264` for `n=16` and `r=6`.